# The greatest trick that he ever pulled was making you believe that he is you

Tags: dialogue, revolver

What does this line from [*Revolver*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0365686/) mean?

> The greatest trick that he ever pulled was making you believe that he is you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As explained by CBS News](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/revolver-is-loaded-with-psycho-babble/):

> But Ritchie is hoping we're captivated by the mind games.
>
> "Revolver" has been advertised with the tagline: "The greatest trick
>   that he ever pulled was making you believe that he is you" -- a
>   rip-off of the famous line from "The Usual Suspects" ("The greatest
>   trick the devil ever pulled was convincing the world he didn't
>   exist").
>
> **To Ritchie, the true enemy lies inside each of us**, and it's only when
>   Green realizes this that he's free. He laments that people are
>   "approval junkies," and Liotta's character is left to symbolize this.
>   In his parting shot, he cries pathetically in his underpants: "Fear
>   me!"

Comment: Even I thought of The Usual Suspects, but having not watched the movie in question, I could not get the link.